# Moment format data timeStamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как мне форматировать время в такой формат (10:00). Если я получаю изначально в таком формате (1624996304) ?

Нужно (10:00)
Есть (1624996304)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const date = 1624996304;
console.log(moment.unix(date).format("h:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```